# tns preview doesn't work doe to unexpected token

Tags: nativescript, preview, tns

Project successfully prepared (ios)
Start sending initial files for device iPhone.
Successfully sent initial files for device iPhone.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at PreviewSdkService. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/livesync/playground/preview-sdk-service.js:100:43)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/livesync/playground/preview-sdk-service.js:4:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Comment: Hey Dan, this issue should be fixed. Could you give it another try?

Answer (score 2):

hey i have exact the same error on same position in preview-sdk-service.js i reinstalled everything with no errors but still the same. i contacted the support, when i get an answer i will let you know. i have also problems with playground today it will not load correctly on my device. btw yesterday it worked like a charm.

---------SUPPORT ANSWER--------------

"we are migrating the auth to use Firebase and looks like couple things are still propagating. An engineer is working on this and should be resolved by Monday"

so its not a user mistake and we can just wait and hope they can fix it quickly.

Comment: Yes there's definitely an issue with Nativescript playground at the minute. Both online GUI and the CLI. Log it with them... we'll hopefully have it sorted sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this exact issue at the moment. Even started a new template using the Angular CLI command:

```
ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics my-mobile-app
```

From the site:

[Angular CLI support](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/angular-cli)

The initial template seem to work but after adding some custom modules this started happening. Running on a Android Virtual Device works.

I've been looking for a solution and the issues seems to ga back as far as 2018 so i'm not sure if this is even een NativeScript issues of a dev environment issues not being setup correctly.